# Firefox CSS sourcemaps not updating rendered page

Tags: firefox, sass, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

I'm attempting to use source maps to live-edit scss in Firefox.
I followed the steps outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor#Source_map_support). My scss sources are visible and editable in the dev tools, but changes made to them are not reflected until I perform a manual page refresh.

My setup:

A local webserver with the following in its document root:

```
/
├── index.html
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   ├── main.css.map
│   │   ├── scss
│   │   │   ├── main.scss
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
   42
</body>
</html>
```

main.scss:

```
body {
   background-color:lightblue;
}
```

And, running in the `css` directory to generate the `main.css` and `main.css.map` files:

```
sass --sourcemap=file --watch scss:.
```

When I go to `localhost/index.html` in Firefox I can see the scss file, but when I save it over `/path/to/document_root/assets/css/scss/main.scss` the "main.css" displayed under it is struck through:

[image]

Saving it triggers sass to rebuild as expected, but Firefox doesn't seem to pick up on the rebuilt css until I refresh.

Comment: Currently this is just a problem report. We need details of your configuration/setup, what you expected to happen, what did happen, and an actual question. Basically, we need a [mcve] to be able to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Can you please mention the Firefox version too?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Firefox-developer 53.0a2

Comment: @Makyen How is it now? I noticed I have a different problem if I visit the file through the filesystem instead of a server; it live-reloads then reverts my changes

Comment: @gandalf3 This does not sound like something that is an issue with how you have written your code. From what you have described, it sounds more like a bug than an issue with something you are doing wrong in your code (i.e. Firefox should be written to account for a large possible set of situations). Have you [looked for bugs and/or filed a bug on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: @Makyen I've now found [974827](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=974827) and reported [1346662](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1346662)